# Shake hands with how many people?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

When the interview is over, I usually shake hands with everyone. This time, there was a jury of 8 people. Time was limited to 45 minutes. Surely they want to take notes etc. before the next candidate comes in (15 minutes later). Anyway, I wanted to shake hands, but some of them refused to. Now I wonder:

Is there a rule of thumb with how many people you should shake hands and when not? Or do special rules apply to situations like this "mass interviewing"?

Comment: You could do like Mr. Spock. Thank you, ladies and genteman, for the interview. LLAP.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably have deduced that from their attitude : if 1s after saying "thank you, we'll be in touch" they were heads down on their notes like you don't exist you should just answer politely and get out. If they kept looking at you, stood up or moveb a bit towards you, that might have been an invitation to shake hands.

This is extremely culture/country dependant, but here's the rule of thumb I apply at work (in France) : the person with the highest position offers or not the handshake. In your situation, I wouldn't have come to shake interviewers' hands if not "invited" (even with just a body language hint) to.